# Verb tense when qualified by αεί/αἰέν

Tags: ancient-greek

In particular, I am wondering about Epic Greek, but I am supposing that the rule is the same in Classical Greek. My question is about what verb tenses are allowed by the adverb αεί when it is qualifying the verb. Even more particularly, can a verb in the future tense be used with αεί/αἰέν?

Answer (score 5):

Is there a reason why it wouldn't apply to the future?

From Aristophanes' *Clouds* 1011-1012:

> **ἕξεις ἀεὶ** στῆθος λιπαρόν
> **You will always have** a smooth chest

Here's another, from Euripides' *Bacchae* 1688:

> **ἔσται** σπονδαῖς ἔντιμος **ἀεί**
> She **will be** honored with libations **forever**.

Comment: Thank you. Truth be told, there seems no semantic rationale that should prohibit so doing. I asked this question , however, because I had thought that I remembered reading that these particular adverbs, “always” and “never”, require the present tense. I pored over my books, but could not find where I might have read that. As it stands, I have no idea where I got that idea from. Can you think of any additional examples using the future?

Comment: I often wish there was such a wonderful online resource for Greek as “PHI texts” provides for Latin, allowing word searches of the entire corpus. I mean, you have Strong’s online, but that only deals with Koine Greek, and of course with Biblical literature.

Comment: @Mike It's definitely not the case that it requires the present. It could be past or future as well. If you want to do a search, you could use [Scaife](https://scaife.perseus.org/search/?q=%CE%B1%CE%B5%CE%AF&kind=lemma&format=instances&p=1). It's not as good as the TLG (which is *far* better than PHI) nor as complete, but it's still very useful for searching Greek texts.

Comment: One potential reason why it wouldn’t apply to the future would be if Greek had different words for ‘always/never [in the past/present]’ and ‘always/never [in the future]’. That’s not unheard of; for example, Irish has multiple words meaning ‘always’ (or ‘never’ in negative contexts), and while some of them are time-indifferent, _go deo_ is only used for the present and future, while _(a)riamh_ is only used for the past. Ἀεί happens not to work like that, but there’s no inherent reason why it couldn’t have.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet True, but that kind of information would have been necessary to be included in the opening question, thus my clarifying question. I think what prompts a question can be even more useful than the question itself.

Comment: Thank you all so much, especially to Cairnavon for all the examples that you provided. I don’t understand how I got this idea in my mind, but I did have the distinct idea that these adverbs introduced the continuous aspect, and that the continuous aspect required the verb in the present tense. Thank you for disabusing me of that misconception.

Comment: @Mike No worries! Glad we can clear that up for you.

Comment: @Mike Don't forget to mark one of the answer solved (probably Cairnarvon's in this since it answers your question more completely than mine).

Answer (score 5):

Since you asked about Epic Greek: in the Iliad and the Odyssey, ἀεί and its variants appear with a present stem 164 times, with an aorist 7 times, with a future 7 times, and with a perfect 19 times.

One example of each (translations from the Murray/Wyatt Loeb):

Present: Il. 1.52

> [...] αἰεὶ δὲ πυραὶ νεκύων καίοντο θαμειαί.
>
> and ever did the pyres of the dead burn thick.

Aorist: Il. 21.263

> ὣς αἰεὶ Ἀχιλῆα κιχήσατο κῦμα ῥόοιο
>
> just so did the flood of the river ever overtake Achilles

Future: Il. 10.217

> αἰεὶ δ᾿ ἐν δαίτῃσι καὶ εἰλαπίνῃσι παρέσται
>
> and always he will be with us at feasts and drinking bouts.

Perfect: Il. 8.408

> αἰεὶ γάρ μοι ἔωθεν ἐνικλᾶν ὅττι κεν εἴπω
>
> since she is always in the habit of thwarting me in whatever I have decreed

When it appears with a present stem, it's an imperfect in 50 of the cases; with a perfect stem, it's a pluperfect in 5 cases. (It's never a future perfect because there are no future perfects in the Iliad or the Odyssey.)

So it doesn't appear as if there are any restrictions regarding aspect or tense when it comes to the use of ἀεί.

(I used the [Ancient Greek Dependency Treebank](https://perseusdl.github.io/treebank_data/) for this, through [DendroSearch](https://en.pedalion.org/node/205069). The undergrads they have producing these trees aren't always great at what they do (I was one of them!), but for Homer it's been pretty solid in my experience.)

Comment: I completely overlooked "epic" in the original question; my eyes jumped straight to Classical Greek. Good post.